# vim : bounce to the nearest enclosing paren

Tags: vim

say I have text such as

```
CREATE TABLE blah blah (
`id` int not null,
`xxxxxx` varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
```

and cursor is on the "xxxxxx" - what can I do to quickly jump to the opening "(" - or the closing one for that matter. I can use "F" but that only finds within the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- Use `[(` ; see `:help [(` for more detail.
- Use `?(` and ENTER. See `:help ?` for more detail.

Comment: close enough - that gets the previous "(", but not necessarily the one enclosing the block the cursor is in. I just found out `[(` is what I want. thanks

Comment: @sbeam: Also see `[m` and `[{` which are very useful if you write C code.